# Why does SimpleDateFormat fail to parse weekday in date string?

Tags: java, date

Running this program:

```
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;
public class xx {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        final SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z", Locale.US);
        format.setLenient(false);
        format.parse("Tue, 16 Jan 2010 04:41:09 -0000");
    }
}
```

Gives this result (`java version "1.7.0_17"`):

```
Exception in thread "main" java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Tue, 16 Jan 2010 04:41:09 -0000"
at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:357)
at xx.main(xx.java:7)
```

It appears that when set to non-lenient mode, the `Tue,` prefix is what fails to parse.

Question is, why does `EEE,` fail to match the `Tue,` prefix of the date string?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because January 16th wasn't a Tuesday, it was a Saturday.

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws ParseException {
    final SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z", Locale.US);
    format.setLenient(false);
    format.parse("Sat, 16 Jan 2010 04:41:09 -0000");
}
```

works just fine.

Comment: D'oh! Thanks. So simple :)

Comment: please tell me you didn't know that off the top of your head? (Stolen from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6841479/1240557) ;))